# display multiple value in table

Tags: jquery, html, css

Actually I have to display in page in table after fetching data from table from same column field .
In same field It is storing data as comma seprated values. please see below.
[image]

I want to show in table only one field of column data in ui like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use `string.split(',')` and js dynamic create table.

```js
var data = "100,200,300,400,500,600";
var split = data.split(",");
tableCreate();

function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
  //Head
  {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var tdId = document.createElement('td')
    var textId = document.createTextNode("ID");
    var tdPartyId = document.createElement('td');
    var textPartyId = document.createTextNode("PartyId");
    tdId.appendChild(textId); 
    tdPartyId.appendChild(textPartyId); 
    tr.appendChild(tdId);  
    tr.appendChild(tdPartyId);    
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
  }  
  //body
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      var tdId = document.createElement('td')
      var textId = document.createTextNode(i+1);
      var tdPartyId = document.createElement('td');
      var textPartyId = document.createTextNode(split[i]);
      tdId.appendChild(textId); 
      tdPartyId.appendChild(textPartyId); 
      tr.appendChild(tdId);  
      tr.appendChild(tdPartyId);    
      tbl.appendChild(tr);
    }    
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl)
}
```

result :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First create array from `data` using `split(",")` function.

Then use array to create table:

```js
let data = "100,200,300,400,500,600";
var new_array= data.split(",");
$("body").append("<table border='1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Party ID</th</tr></table>");
new_array.forEach(function(data,key){
   $("table").append("<tr><td>"+(key+1)+"</td><td>"+data+"</td></tr>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*It is easy to create and append elements by using jquery*